# Date Picker Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola buenos días estoy intentando implementar un data Picker en Bootstrap lo cual funciona pero lo que no me resulta es agregar el **Glyphicons**, e visto un par de tutoriales pero aun no lo logro resolver. lo que he hecho hasta el momento es lo siguiente.

```
  <div class="form-group row" id='datetimepicker'>
   <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">fecha</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="date" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-addon" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Appular Admin</title>
  <!-- plugins:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../vendors/iconfonts/font-awesome/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../vendors/css/vendor.bundle.addons.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- plugin css for this page -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.urbanui.com/">
  <!-- End plugin css for this page -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../css/vertical-layout-light/style.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../../images/favicon.png" />
</head>
```

Comment: importaste tanto los js como los css, relacionados al date picker ?

Comment: tienes que tener implementado dicha libreria de iconos glyphicon dado que en la actual version de bootstrap 4 no viene ya esta..

Comment: agregue el head donde según yo están agregadas y referencia das las librerías necesarias del boostrap 3 que estoy usando.

Comment: @NicolasRudisky que versión de bootstrap estas utilizando?